# web service call : Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Tags: hibernate

Sorry I am asking the common question 
    I am getting below exception when two web service calls the same method and each time calls method isUserValid(). User validation return true but still getting the exception. why only at second call it throws exception, I am calling second web service before first get ended.
Is there a way that both ws call execute separately.

```
 org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.dmainc.commons.security.User#4]
```

problem method-

```
public UpdateFileRequest getUpdateFragment(UpdateFilter filter)
  {
  Session session = null;
  Transaction transaction = null;

  UpdateFileRequest request = new UpdateFileRequest();
  UpdateFragmentReleaseFilter releaseFilter = null;

  try
  {
     session = HibernateUtils.currentSession();
     transaction = session.beginTransaction();

     releaseFilter = new UpdateFragmentReleaseFilter(filter);

     // are the user credentials valid
     if(ServiceUtils.isUserValid(releaseFilter))
     {
      //Getting exception at this place while committing the transacation
       HibernateUtils.commit(transaction);
     }
```

currentSession method

```
public static Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session s = session.get();

    if(s != null)
       s = validateSession(s);

    // Open a new Session, if this Thread has none yet
    if (s == null) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("Opening new session");
        s = session_factory.openSession();

        session.set(s);
        new_session.set(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else if (!isNewSession()) {
        new_session.set(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ServiceUtils.isUserValid(releaseFilter) only reads information in the database, and does not change anything? Could you attach the code of ServiceUtils.isUserValid(releaseFilter)?

Comment: @JohnDonn , after allwing show sql, I found that it was actually modifying the user table, thats why it was throwing exception. actully Its updating login timestamp(passwordAttemptDate) and the same time other thread is tring to modifying/commit. this operation is under two different transaction, Dont knwo how to restrict the user object, I am adding piece which causing the issue.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by removing version field in user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve the issue by creating new session on each web service call inspite of using the ongoing session.